# Matrix multiplication of numpy ndarrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a two numpy arrays `a`, `B` like this.

```
>> a 
[1 2 3]
>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>> B
[[1 2 3]
 [2 2 7]
 [3 4 6]]
>> type(B)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I want to do the matrix multiplication like `a * B * a_transpose` which is `(1*3)*(3*3)*(3*1)` type matrix multiplication which should result in `(1*1)`.

How do I do this in `numpy`?

Comment: Did you do some efforts to solve it, it is very simple problem if you surf the internet a little bit?

Comment: @Hamzah I have been stuck for hours on this. I just learned about numpy array and numpy matrix. But couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You have to do 2 multiplications. Which one seems impossible? What did you try with your 2 arrays?

Comment: `a` is not (1 x 3).  Shape is (3,).  `a.T` has the same shape.

Comment: The numpy `dot` and `matmul/@` work just fine with 1d arrays like `a`.  Read their documentation..  Normally you don't need to distinguish between 'row vector' and 'column vector'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.T` is the transpose of matrix `a`

```
temp = np.dot(a, B)        # a * B

final= np.dot(temp, a.T)   #(a * B) * a_transpose
```

Answer for your example is `155`

Comment: Doesn't `a.T` have the same value as `a`? Is it necessary?

Comment: @Mike , yes, ``a.T`` is the same of ``a`` but the shape is the opposite for example, if ``a`` is in 1*3 shape, ``a.T`` will be in 3*1 shape.

Comment: `a=np.array([3,1,2])
print(a.shape)
at=(a.T)
print(at.shape)`
I did this and the output is `(3,)
(3,)` in both cases? What does that mean?

Comment: @Mike , in numpy if you have a row vector or column vector, you will get (3,) instead of (3,1)

Comment: But then what's the point of shape? How does `a` and `a.T` differ? In terms of how they stored in memory?

Comment: @Mike In numpy, one-dimensional arrays do not have a second dimension, so the transpose operation doesn't change the shape.

Comment: @Mike If you want ``a`` to behave like a row vector (1x3) and ``a.T`` to behave like a column vector (3x1), you should reshape ``a`` into a two-dimensional array. You can do this using the ``reshape`` method.

Comment: a = a.reshape(1, -1) 
print(a.shape)

at = a.T 
print(at.shape)

Comment: If I have `numpy.ndarray` `a` of shape `(3,)` Is it possible to use `np.dot` or `@` for getting outer product(`a*a.T` which is `3*3` matrix)?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [2, 2, 7],
              [3, 4, 6]])
```

---

```
(a@B)@a

#output
155
```

Comment: why `a.T`?  `a  is 1d

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.einsum`:

```
np.einsum("i,ij,j->", a,B,a)
> 155
```

or matrix multiplication with

```
[a] @ (B @ a)
> np.array([155])
```

Comment: What's the point `[]` in '[a]' in 2nd snippet?

Comment: @Mike I thought I need it to make it work, I don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a matrix multiplication with "@" and you can obtain the transpose of the vector "a" with a.transpose(), so you need to do:

a @b @a

Comment: Please format your answer as valid code.

Comment: `a` is 1d.  transpose does not change that!

Comment: That's right, thanks!